# Timeout on execution of query in CodeIgniter 3. Bulk data delete?

Tags: php, timeout, codeigniter-3, sql-delete, server-error

I am trying to **delete bulk data from database** through selected rows, but it is giving me an error about the max-time execution limit, but when I try to delete data **less than 1000 rows** it works fine, do you have an idea basically what the problem is?
I have also increased the upload_max_filesize, memory_limit, max_input_time, max_execution_time in my server setting and it's still giving this error.

Here is the code in my model:

function deletePosts($ids = array()){

```
    $this->db->where_in('id',$ids);
    $this->db->delete('post_code_delivery');
  return 1;
```

}

code in my controller :

```
  public function deletePosts(){

   $ids = $this->input->post('ids'); 
   $this->load->model('mdl_post_code');
   $this->mdl_post_code->deletePosts($ids);
   echo 0;
    die;
```

}

my view :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxc2n.png)

Comment: Why do people ask with their code as image?

Comment: You'll need to identify _where_ the timeout happens. But in general the timeout means: it takes too long to finish the operation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, basically i am sending an array to the function to delete the all included items id's in the array. Sometimes when i passed an array with maximum range of 1000 items it proceed accurately but when i try to submit the array with more than 3000 or 4000 items in the array it make a timeout error, and the operation does not complete. I have increased execution time on the server but it's still with more than 3000 items. is any way to resolve that issue?

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: is my question written well now. Actually this is my first question on stack overflow